# How in groovy to use the newBlockingStub method from google protocol buffers?

Tags: java, groovy, protocol-buffers, grpc-java, proto

In my `Protocol.proto` file I have an RPC defined as follows:

```
message Task {
    // My own fields
}  
message Result {
    // My own fields
}

service ClientListener {
    rpc SendTask(Task) returns (Result);
}
```

In the Groovy language file, I want to create a blocking client. The problem is that I can't find a way to use the `newBlockingStub` method, if I try to call it like this:

```
import Protocol.ClientListener;
import Protocol.ClientListener.BlockingStub;

ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 8080).usePlaintext().build();
BlockingStub stub = ClientListener.newBlockingStub(channel);
```

then

```
No signature of method: static  ClientListener.newBlockingStub() is applicable for
argument types: (io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper) values: 
[ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper{delegate=ManagedChannelImpl{logId=1, 
                                               target=localhost:8080}}] 
Possible solutions: newBlockingStub(com.google.protobuf.BlockingRpcChannel)
```

error is thrown.

Alternatively, I see other tutorials are importing a class CustomServiceName**Grpc**, but
when I try to import such class:

```
import Protocol.ClientListenerGrpc;
```

I get an error

```
Groovy: unable to resolve class Protocol.ClientListenerGrpc
```

**So how to import newBlockingStub method**?

My maven file has these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
    <version>1.27.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
    <version>1.27.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
    <version>1.27.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

and it compiles all proto classes for `Task` and `Result` and `ClientListener`, but not `ClientListenerGrpc`

It seems that maven does not compile ClientListenerGrpc class, why?

Comment: Is this your real error or is this some sort of copy and paste error? `newBlockingStubbbb` (note the many `b`)

Comment: @cfrick this was copy paste error, only one b is present at the end if the actual error.

Comment: The error message you fixed usually continues to state the inputs and also suggest methods with similar names or similar arguments.  Have you left that out or is there really no more output?

Comment: @cfrick I added more output of that error message.

Comment: how did you compile protobuf? did you use `protobuf-maven-plugin`?

Comment: @creamsoup I added dependency `protobuf-maven-plugin` now. I compile and run the code with `mvn test` command. My `.proto` file gets compiled to many classes that include a class for `Task` and `Client` as well as `ClientListener`, however there is no class `ClientListenerGrpc`

Comment: it is hard to tell from partial `pom.xml` and proto definition. you shouldn't add `protobuf-maven-plugin` as dependency, it should be in plugins section. see working example pom in grpc-java repo: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/pom.xml   near L93.